# How to configure home Ubuntu like web server linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web-server

I have installed ubuntu on my computer.
Now i want to make it same like we have linux on VPS.

So that i can make websites just like on online vps but by using local IP.

IN my online VPS i use cpanel and WHM.
Can i use similar software on home ubuntu.

What are the other alternatives to make webistes on local ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course:

```
$ apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server
```

Add/remove packages depending your desired environment and Bob's your Uncle.

Now - *hosting* websites on your home computer...that's another issue altogether. I assume you're just hoping to use the local machine for development, correct?

--

Edit: If you want a WHM-like control panel without having to purchase software, you can look into [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/index.html) and [Virtualmin](http://www.webmin.com/virtualmin.html). That said, I'd *highly* suggest you learn how to set up your server without the aid of these GUI packages. The likelihood is fairly high that, someday, you'll need to make changes on a server that doesn't have these tools installed. If you learn how to do these tasks on the CLI, you'll be all set.

Comment: yes i just want for local development

Answer (score 0):

WHM is a commercial product -- go buy a copy and sure, you can run it on your home box.